# Invalid grant error message and invalid tokens after a week

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

##### Environment details

- Node version: `v12.22.8`
- NPM version: `6.14.15`
- google apis version: `72.0.0`
- google auth library version: `7.0.4`
- environment variables: `clientId`, `clientSecret`, `redirectUri`

### Issues

- google cloud functions are implemented and are using `gmail` service from `googleApis` and `oAuth2Client` from `google-auth-library` packages
- tokens are created when login into a gmail service account and stored in a db from which are read when tokens are needed
- tokens are refreshed every hour by setting a cron job on a cloud function that refreshes tokens
- after a week tokens get invalid even after refreshing them every hour

#### Cloud functions used in application

cloud functions are deployed on GCP
functions `1)` and `2)` are triggered only once
on function `3)` is set the cron job every hour
on function `4)` is set the cron job every day

The whole issue with a little bit of explanation an a bit of code is submitted here: [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2886)

Comment: Your using service account authorization?   Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 1):

I can see by the code that you posted on Github that you are using Oauth2 to authorize your users.  You are not using service account authentication.

```
new googleAuth.OAuth2Client({ clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri})
```

Apps that are in test have their refresh tokens expired after seven days.

To fix it up your application into production.

[Refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

## set to prodctuion

go to google cloud console for your project under the oauth2 consent screen

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now I know what causes it, but I how do I put the app into a production mode, do I set in in gcp?

Comment: Its in Google cloud console under the consent screen.  Sorry should have mentioned that how to set it in my answer 

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and even for showing me how to set it up 